# Verilog Difference Between Regular wire and wire[] + Period in front of variable name

Tags: verilog

I have two questions regarding Verilog HDL.

1. What is the difference between regular `wire` and, for example, `wire[31:0]`?
2. What does it mean when a variable has a period in front of it? (*e.g.* `.clk   (clk 0)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1st question,

```
wire a;  //a is one bit.
wire [31:0] a;  //a is 32 bit.
```

As for 2nd question, it's way of instantiation a sub-module in a main module. Suppose you have the following module,

```
module arith(
    A,
    B
    );
```

And you want to instantiate it in a top module. Then,

```
arith uut1 (
        .A(A_in_topmodule), 
        .B(B_in_topmodule)
    );
```

Read in detailed about various instantiation methods in Verilog [here](http://verilogcodes.blogspot.in/2015/10/module-instantiation-methods-in-verilog.html).

Comment: I actually have another question... Then for example, if I were to draw a schematic, how do I know which instantiations are input and output? For example, in the example you gave regarding `arith uut1`, among `.A` and `.B` which one is input and which one is output?

Comment: afaik you cannot mention the input or output in instantiation. I would use comments in such a case. Also naming the ports in a smart way will help too. like A_in and B_out.

Comment: the module definition should contain port directions. There are 3 possibilities `input`, `output`, and `inout`. if none mentioned, `inout` is the default. So, provided that the above example has no further into, `A` and `B` are bidirectional `inout` ports.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Serge